# Can you better explain the semantics of TestNG's @BeforeTest annotation?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng

I read the [relevant documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html) and didn't understand it. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310964/testngs-beforetest-on-base-class-only-happening-once-per-fixture/4311427#4311427).

Answer (score 1):

To understand that, you must understand [`testng.xml`](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-xml). Now reread the same thing,

> The annotated method will be run
>   before any test method belonging to
>   the classes inside the `<test>` tag is
>   run.

It should be clear that this annotation will only work with the methods those belong to the classes defined under `<test>` tag in `testng.xml`.