# BeforeTest would not run before every Test method of the class in <test> tag

Tags: java, annotations, testng

Inquiring further into [SO-4310964](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310964/testngs-beforetest-on-base-class-only-happening-once-per-fixture) , I went through the description of annotations at [test.org](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations).

> @BeforeTest: The annotated method will be run before any test method
>   belonging to the classes inside the `test` tag is run.

Now what we have in our code is as follows :

**MyTests.java**

```
public class MyTests {
    @BeforeTest
    public void preTest(){
        //Want to perform some action, suppose clear a Hashmap
        System.out.println("Before Test Called!");
    }

    @Test(groups = {"SanityTests"}, testName = "test1")
    public void Test1(){
            System.out.println("test1");
    }

    @Test(groups = {"SanityTests"}, testName = "test2")
    public void Test2(){
            System.out.println("test2");
    }
}
```

**Sanity-Test.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="SanityTests" verbose="1" >
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="com.android.MyTestsListener" />
    </listeners>

    <test name="sanityAndroid">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.android.MyTests" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Note : I know that @BeforeMethod solves the problem. But to my understanding the link details that the @BeforeTest[`preTest`] method would run before any @Test[`test1`,`test2`] method which belong to the `class` inside the `<test>` tag. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I think you need to tag BeforeTest with the same tag as your tests (SanityTests).

Comment: you mean something like `@BeforeTest(groups = "SanityTests")`?

Comment: Not 100% sure -  or mark it with alwaysRun=true.

Comment: Suggestions are correct by @assylias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**BeforeTest**: The annotated method will be run before **any** test method belonging to the classes inside the `<test>` tag is run

Focus on the "Before **any** test method", not **every** test method.

Now, if the test tag have 2 classes as follow:

```
<test name="sanityAndroid">
    <classes>
        <class name="com.android.MyTests1" />
        <class name="com.android.MyTests2" />
    </classes>
</test>
```

Class MyTest1 have @Test methods as test1 , test2 and
Class MyTest2 have @Test methods as test3 , test4.

So, BeforeTest method will run before any of the test methods i.e test1, test2, test3, test4 belonging to classes i.e. MyTest1, MyTest2 inside the `<test>` tag.

Execution becomes BeforeTest -> (test1, test2, test3, test4) acc to dependency.

Similar to this is AfterTest: The annotated method will be run **after all the test methods** belonging to the classes inside the `<test>` tag have run.

Comment: oh got it. just the way to read it. I knew must have been misunderstood somewhere. Thanx