# Can I have a Base test Class just for using @BeforeTest method in testNG

Tags: java, eclipse, testng

I am writing TestNG automation code for my project . In this I should Login in an account before the test starts (This applies for all test classes) .
Is this possible that I create a class "BaseClass" that has only @BeforeTest annotated method .
Does my test classes identifies the base class  .Or can I follow any other methods .
The reason I am going for a base class is that I dont like to repeat the @BeforeTest method in each test classes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TestNg's @BeforeTest on base class only happening once per fixture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310964/testngs-beforetest-on-base-class-only-happening-once-per-fixture)

Comment: Looking at the answer for question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30587454/difference-between-beforeclass-and-beforetest-in-testng might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, This is possible. We can have a BaseTestClass which is extended by all test classes and use @BeforeTest method in BaseTestClass to run before every test in every class that extends this.

```
public class BaseTestClass {
    @BeforeClass
    public void initializeTestClass() {
        System.out.println("Before class");
    }
}

public class TestClassA extends BaseTestClass {
    @Test
    public void testA() {
        System.out.println("Test A");
    }
}

public class TestClassB extends BaseTestClass {
    @Test
    public void testB() {
        System.out.println("Test B");
    }
}
```

In this above code, Output while running a suite that contains testClassA and TestClassB be like

```
Before Class
Test A
Before Class
Test B
```

Although as far as I have seen, This is a bad practice as when the testng scope becomes larger, The code becomes messier.